# Revoking privileges from role that inherits from object's owner

Tags: postgresql, roles, privileges

I have done this set of instructions:

```
    CREATE ROLE master
      SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE
       VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

SET role = master;

CREATE TABLE test
(
  name text

)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE test
  OWNER TO master;

CREATE ROLE inherited LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT master TO inherited;


set role=master;
REVOKE select on test from inherited cascade;
```

Anybody can tell me why can I still do SELECT on table test?
this one still works:

```
set role=inherited;
select * from test;
```

Role inherited inherits after owner of the object - so that's probably a problem. But is there a way to revoke select anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it because the owner is assumed to have full permissions to the table.

You also have to revoke access to the owning role.